# EXC_BAD_ACCESS signal received when clicking navigation a UIBarButtonItem?

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have an application in which I'm trying to implement the LibPusher API for the chat application.

That API is arc enabled and I've included that in my nonarc project.
It's working fine except for some warnings.

Now my problem is i have added a button in the navigation bar like this:

```
UIButton *btnNext1 =[[UIButton alloc] init];
    [btnNext1 setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"back_btn.png"] forState:UIControlStateNormal];

    btnNext1.frame = CGRectMake(100, 100,60, 31);
    UIBarButtonItem *btnNext =[[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithCustomView:btnNext1];
    [btnNext1 addTarget:self action:@selector(backButtonClicked) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = btnNext;
    [btnNext1 release];
```

It was working fine and in the action i am doing this:

```
PusherPresenceEventsViewController *rootView = ( PusherPresenceEventsViewController*)[self.navigationController.viewControllers objectAtIndex:1];
rootView.newmessage =@"";
[self.navigationController popToViewController:rootView animated:YES];
[rootView release];
```

It's also working fine for the first two times.
However, on the third time it is giving bad access error.
I'm not understanding where I went wrong, can anybody help me?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
UIButton *btnNext1 =    [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom]
```

and don't release it .Also release Rootview since you are not allocating it.

Comment: Correction: I think you meant "Also do _not_ release `rootView` since you are not allocating it." This is the source of the problem, and I think it has nothing to do with the `UIButton` code.

Answer (score 3):

As iProgrammer correctly identified, the problem is that you're releasing something that you do not own (per the [basic memory management rules](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html), you only "own" those things that you created via methods starting with `alloc`, `new`, `copy`, and `mutableCopy`). Remove the `[rootView release]` and your problem should go away.

By the way, I'd suggest running your code through the static analyzer (select "Analyze" on the "Product" menu, or press <kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>command</kbd>+<kbd>B</kbd>). You should have *zero* warnings generated by the analyzer. This extra `release` is an example of the sort of issue that the analyzer would have probably brought to your attention. The static analyzer is excellent at finding all sorts of basic memory management problems that tend to plague non-ARC code.